# how to call a javascript function of server side jsp file from typescript

Tags: typescript

Not able to call javascript function from external jsp file in typescript file in angular project. i want to call a function of jsp file on click of button event of my angular application .

File path is as like:  "https://ServerName/plugin/filename.jsp";

Comment: What do you mean by `external jsp file` ?  Is that a file in your project (ie you're using angular for the front-end, from a Java/JSP back end - and this `filename.jsp` is just one file that you're not using on your current page), or is it from some totally different project you have no control over?

Comment: This file is totally from different server. It's not a part of current project server.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't.

A JSP file is "JavaServer Pages" file, meaning it is a template file that the external system's Java program would use to generate an HTML page.  As such, it would have tags and syntax, etc that would be un-interpretable by your angular project.

The best I can suggest is that you copy out the function(s) that you want into your own Javascript file that you can then reference in your project.

If it is important to keep your system in sync with that other system, then you would have to ask them if they could perform this extraction into some common library for you to both use (so they would know you as a dependent project).